# How to convert json array and unmarshal it with golang

Tags: arrays, json, unmarshalling

I have this json:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 683,
            "nome": "Premier League 19/20",
            "nomeDaTaca": "Premier League",
            "temporada": "2019/2020",
            "categoria": "NACIONAL",
            "temClassificacao": true,
            "temClassificacaoPorGrupo": false,
            "tipoDeColeta": "ESTATISTICA_TOTAL",
            "faseAtual": "Primeira Fase",
            "quantidadeDeEquipes": "20",
            "rodadaAtual": 22,
            "quantidadeDeRodadas": 38,
            "urlLogo": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/logos.footstast.net/campeonatos/Ingles.png",
            "pais": null,
            "sde": {
                "campeonato_id": null,
                "edicao_id": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "pagination": null
}
```

I need to "unmarshal" in go, with a correct struct. I tried to many sites to convert this in struct, but when I "unmarshal", returns nil.

What is the correctly format struct and how I "unmarshal" in to this struct.

I need an example how "unmarshal" correctly. Tks!!

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried? If you don't want struct mandatory, then you can easily convert to the map. See how to convert JSON to map in the answer section

Comment: I posted another, with the code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using some online sample APIs to show the example.

The below dummy API is used to get employees list and parse

http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

[image]

using https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to generate the structure from the JSON

[image]

and see the code which I have tested and works for me. Since AutoGenerated is having an array of Data inside use `var data AutoGenerated` for Unmarshal you can use `data.Data` to get the array.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    type AutoGenerated struct {
        Status string `json:"status"`
        Data   []struct {
            ID             string `json:"id"`
            EmployeeName   string `json:"employee_name"`
            EmployeeSalary string `json:"employee_salary"`
            EmployeeAge    string `json:"employee_age"`
            ProfileImage   string `json:"profile_image"`
        } `json:"data"`
    }
    url := "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    client := &http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error on response.\n[ERRO] -", err)
    }
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    var data AutoGenerated

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &data)

    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

In addition to this, if you don't know all expected key-value pair in response

You can use the below function to convert any JSON array to Map array so that it can be easily iterated or used in golang

```
func stringToMap(data string) []map[string]interface{} {

   var value []map[string]interface{}

   err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &value)

   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   return value
}
```

Comment: Ok, see the another post in this topic! Tks!

Comment: @AndréLuisReisLopes Check my updated answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank's Ashmil! I Was absent for health reasons. That's it! It worked now!

Comment: @AndréLuisReisLopes upvote the answer if it helps, welcome

Answer (score 0):

First of all I appreciate your help. My code is simply to get the result of this json (which comes from a Restfull API).

Then I have to deserialize this data to save it in a database.

My difficulty is understanding the return json structure, which contains a top array.

Like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 683,
            "nome": "Premier League 19/20",
```

My Struct: (I used https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to convert for me!

```
type Campeonato struct {
    Data []struct {
        ID                       int         `json:"id"`
        Nome                     string      `json:"nome"`
        NomeDaTaca               string      `json:"nomeDaTaca"`
        Temporada                string      `json:"temporada"`
        Categoria                string      `json:"categoria"`
        TemClassificacao         bool        `json:"temClassificacao"`
        TemClassificacaoPorGrupo bool        `json:"temClassificacaoPorGrupo"`
        TipoDeColeta             string      `json:"tipoDeColeta"`
        FaseAtual                string      `json:"faseAtual"`
        QuantidadeDeEquipes      string      `json:"quantidadeDeEquipes"`
        RodadaAtual              int         `json:"rodadaAtual"`
        QuantidadeDeRodadas      int         `json:"quantidadeDeRodadas"`
        URLLogo                  string      `json:"urlLogo"`
        Pais                     interface{} `json:"pais"`
        Sde                      struct {
            CampeonatoID interface{} `json:"campeonato_id"`
            EdicaoID     interface{} `json:"edicao_id"`
        } `json:"sde"`
    } `json:"data"`
    Pagination interface{} `json:"pagination"`
}
```

My Code to unmarshal: It's consume an API, but i don't have permission to publicate the bearer token variable. You can explan with another public API as sample?

```
func main() {

    url := "http://apifutebol.footstats.net/3.0/campeonatos"

    var bearer = " - I don't have permission to publicate it - "

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error on response.\n[ERRO] -", err)
    }

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    //fmt.Println(string([]byte(body)))

    var data []Campeonato

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &data)

}
```

The return is  !

Thank you so much!

Comment: since your structure having a list Data []struct, I believe 'var data []Campeonato' is wrong 'var data Campeonato' this should do the need, I will try with some sample API and will share here soon.

Comment: better edit the question for others visibility, have a look into Stackoverflow Code of Conduct

Comment: is there any error, did you tried the request in postman. verify the request in a postman then try printing your body directly and make sure the request gives an exact response. because the unmarshal code is working fine with me.